# Convert Nginx upstream directive to Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I want to write Apache upstream variable which would be like this in Nginx

```
upstream ghs {
  ip_hash;
  server ghs.google.com;
  server 74.125.43.121;
  server 74.125.47.121;
  server 74.125.53.121;
}
```

this can be used after ward as a variable which can be given to other directives e.g.

```
proxy_pass http://ghs/;
```

What is the equivalent of this for Apache?

Answer (score 2):

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    # WebHead1
    BalancerMember http://10.x.x.x:80

    # WebHead2
    BalancerMember http://10.x.x.x:80

    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
```

[Taken from here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/simple-load-balancing-with-apache)